# Operator > and combining it with number and a string in NetLogo

Tags: netlogo

I want a little help. I want turtles to cooperate with 50% probability if their land parcels are > 5.
I am writing as

```
ifelse  random 1 = 0 and land > 5
                         [set cooperate? true]
                         [set cooperate? false]
```

But it gives error that; The > operator can only be used on two numbers, two strings, or two agents of the same type, but not on a string and a number.
how to correct it?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's not quite enough information to diagnose the problem. Is this code inside an `ask turtles` block with the variable 'land' as a `turtles-own` attribute? Also, you might want to print off some values of 'land' to make sure you actually have numbers in it.

As you can see from the working example below, there is no error in the code you have provided.

```
turtles-own [ land cooperate? ]

to testme
  clear-all
  create-turtles 10
  [ set land random 10
    ifelse  random 1 = 0 and land > 5
    [ set cooperate? true ]
    [ set cooperate? false ]
  ]
  type "Cooperating: " print count turtles with [cooperate?]
  type "Not cooperating: " print count turtles with [not cooperate?]
end
```